# My tablet is not turning on

Tags: battery, charging

I have a tablet not  two years old, a few days ago it was left in a hot truck for about two days. Now it won't go past "fast boot menu".

I have tried everything, I even tried charging it and the battery keeps saying 0%, how can I charge my tablet and turn it on?

Answer (score 0):

There's a fairly good chance you overheated a component in the device. Most likely a charging component or someone. There isn't much you can do besides going to a phone/tablet repair shop. But that could cost more than the tablet itself.

Answer (score 0):

- Heat is the worst enemy of batteries and your battery being two years old would have suffered damage by "baking" it in the truck for two days
- Batteries tend to [self discharge](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/elevating_self_discharge) , higher the temperature, more the discharge
- As a result, the battery voltage could have fallen to a very low level, wherein a protection circuit kicks in and [prevents further charging](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/low_voltage_cut_off). There are ways to overcome this but it is best left to  qualified technicians to handle it

That said, all I can suggest is take it to a service center. Don't attempt to charge